# Safely coercing units from Wolfram|Alpha freeform input

Tags: units, free-form-input

How do I coerce unexpected units from free-form input? For instance, if I request the binding energy of hydrogen I expect an answer with dimensions of energy. Instead I get

```
List[Quantity[13.5979217890159720235`5.,"MolarElectronvolts"]]
```

It is also deceptive because the front-end prints it as `{13.598 eV}`. If you try to do something like divide it by a fundamental charge and convert to volts, it will complain. Now I'm sure there is some coercion possible like

[image]

but this method is extremely fragile-- it is only going to work if you recognize already that the number you get from the query is the correct one, in which case it is almost pointless to use the free-form input. Also if the free-form input gave me a binding energy in terms of `MolarKiloelectronvolts` or something then doing this would screw everything up.

Is there a way to tell the free-form input, "When I ask for an energy give me something with dimensions of energy"?

Comment: You are probably looking for the function [``UnitConvert``](https://reference.wolram.com/language/ref/UnitConvert.html). Or write "hydrogen binding energy in electronvolts" in the free-form input.

Comment: If it works feel free to write it as an answer after trying it out and I will accept @Domen

Comment: `UnitConvert[(Entity["Element", "Hydrogen"]["IonizationEnergies"])*(Quantity[1,"Moles"]/Quantity[1, "AvogadroNumber"]), "Electronvolts"]` or `UnitSimplify[(Entity["Element", "Hydrogen"]["IonizationEnergies"])*(Quantity[1, "Moles"]/Quantity[1, "AvogadroNumber"])]`